# Issue implementing groups (invoked_subcommand returning None always)

Tags: discord, discord.py

My (quite appalling, though hopefully that isn't going to be the issue here) code for a quotebot cog on a discord bot running Discord.py has hit a bit of an issue. I've had a lot of issues trying to implement groups in the past and I had always previously given up, but I want to do things proper this time because the code has just gotten to unwieldy to do otherwise. The thing is, though, I don't really know what I'm doing. My code so far:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import json
from . import utils
import random
import math

"""Module containing all you need for a quote bot"""

data = utils.load_json("quotes")

maxID = data["maxID"]

temp = data["quotes"]
quotes = []

curPage = 0

class Quote:
    def __init__(self, id, msg):
        self.id = id
        self.msg = msg

for i in range(0, len(temp[0])):
    quotes.append(Quote(temp[1][i], temp[0][i]))

class Quotes():

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    #All the "Quote" commands
    @commands.group(pass_context=True)
    async def quote(self, ctx, arg):
        print(ctx.message.content)
        if ctx.invoked_subcommand == None:
            global quotes
            global maxID

            try:
                if int(arg) <= maxID and int(arg) >= 1:
                    b = None
                    for s in quotes:
                        if int(arg) - 1 == s.id:
                            b = s
                            break

                    if (b == None):
                        await ctx.channel.send('No quote with this ID')
                        return
                    await ctx.channel.send('`Quote ' + str(int(arg)) +':` ' + str(b.msg))
                else:
                    await ctx.channel.send('No quote with this ID')
            except:
                await ctx.channel.send('Invalid input')

    @quote.command(pass_context=True)
    async def add(self, ctx, *args):
        global maxID
        global quotes

        quotes.append(Quote(maxID, s))
        maxID += 1
        await ctx.channel.send('`Added Quote ID: ' + str(maxID) + '`')

    @quote.command(pass_context=True)
    async def list(self, ctx):
        global quotes

        try:
            m = []
            for q in quotes:
                m.append(q.msg + " | id = " + str(q.id + 1))
            pages = utils.Pages(self.bot, message=ctx.message, entries=m, per_page=15)
            await pages.paginate(start_page=1)
        except utils.CannotPaginate as e:
            print(e)

    @quote.command(pass_context=True)
    async def random(self, ctx):
        global quotes

        i = random.randint(0,len(quotes) - 1)
        await ctx.channel.send('`Quote ' + str(quotes[i].id) +':` ' + str(quotes[i].msg))

    @quote.command(pass_context=True)
    async def remove(self, ctx, arg):
        global quotes
        global maxID

        try:
            i = int(arg) - 1
            if i < maxID and i >= 0:
                b = None
                for s in quotes:
                    if i == s.id:
                        b = s
                        break

                if b != None:
                    quotes.remove(b)
                    await ctx.channel.send('`Removed Quote ID: ' + str(i + 1) + '`')
                else:
                    await ctx.channel.send('No quote with this ID')
            else:
                await ctx.channel.send('No quote with this ID')
        except ValueError as e:
            await ctx.channel.send('Invalid input')

    def __unload():
        global quotes
        global maxID

        out = [[0 for x in range(len(quotes))] for y in range(2)]
        for i in range(0, len(quotes)):
            out[0][i] = quotes[i].msg
            out[1][i] = quotes[i].id

        data["quotes"] = out
        data["maxID"] = maxID

        utils.save_json(data, "quotes")
        utils.save_json(data, "Backups\quotes_backup")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Quotes(bot))
```

This hacked-together junk of code is my quote bot. I can at the very least the commands ran fine before I started moving them into a group, so that much is known. The issue is that in the parent function quote() it appears that ctx.invoked_subcommand is ALWAYS returning None. I don't know if I'm missing something or if I'm doing something wrong, but the exact input I give the bot is "->quote list" and, as far as I can tell, that should be correct. Last thing to note is that, according to the built in help, it does recognize Quote as a group and when I do "->help quote" it comes up with the proper help structure. Thank you in advance, I'm certain the issue here isn't too hard and I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: You should consider switching to the rewrite branch, just because `ext.commands` is much better documented there.  I think the problem is arising from the arguments to `quote`.  Try printing out `arg` inside `quote`.  I bet you'll see that when you call `quote list`, `list` is being put in `arg` and not called as a subcommand.  You may be able to pass [`invoke_without_command=True`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoked_subcommand#discord.Group.invoke_without_command) into `commands.group` to only process that coroutine if there is no subcommand.

Answer (score 2):

As Patrick Haugh has commented, your subcommands are being passed into your `arg` parameter. Remove `arg`from `async def quote(self, ctx, arg):` and it should work

(give his comment an upvote if this helps)